# Phonegap pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY doesn't work with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova

Without angular it's work fine:

```
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Album</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  alert(imageURI)
}

function getPhoto(source) {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.imageURI,
    sourceType: source });
}

function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
    </script>
```

But when I'm trying to use angular 2 and my code doesn't work:

```
<button (click)="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY)">From Photo Album</button>

getPhoto(source) {
    alert(111);
    navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onSuccess, this.onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.imageURI,
        sourceType: source });
}
onSuccess(imageData) {
    this.photo = imageURI;
}
onFail(message) {
    alert('Photo not loaded, because: ' + message);
}
```

When I click on the button, getPhoto function doesn't work. Because of pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY in the function.

Answer (score 0):

This API is probably not patched by Angulars zone. Try using zone explicitely

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

getPhoto(source) {
  alert(111);
  zone.run(() => {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onSuccess, this.onFail, { quality: 50,
      destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.imageURI,
      sourceType: source });
  });
}
```

(not sure if the syntax is correct though, I'm not a TS developer)